# On-demand rendering of precompiled Vue.js components (webpack 2)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-loader

I'm trying to on-demand render vue components. Application consists of 4 parts, each should be rendered to the DOM only after calling some function, something like `renderProducts()`

I'm using webpack 2 with latest vue-loader (+ Vuex, Vuei18n, ...)
The problem is, this only works when using standalone build (with webpack alias for vue: `vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js'`).

But I think I can do better, and use runtime-only build (and save some kilobytes).

Anyone knows, what am I doing wrong?
Here's my application entrypoint (showing only relevant parts):

```
import './index.scss';
import Vue from 'vue';

import MenusComponent from './components/menus/_menus-root.vue';
import CartComponent from './components/cart/_cart-root.vue';
import NavigationComponent from './components/navigation/_navigation-root.vue';
import LocationInfoComponent from './components/location-info/_location-info-root.vue';

...

const menus = new Vue({ name: 'menus-root', render: h => h(MenusComponent), store });
const cart = new Vue({ name: 'cart-root', render: h => h(CartComponent), store });
const navigation = new Vue({ name: 'navigation-root', render: h => h(NavigationComponent), store });
const locationInfo = new Vue({ name: 'location-info-root', render: h => h(LocationInfoComponent), store });

...

window.renderMenus = ({ el }) => {
  menus.$mount(el);
},
window.renderCart = ({ el }) => {
  cart.$mount(el);
},
window.renderNavigation = ({ el }) => {
  navigation.$mount(el);
},
window.renderLocationInfo = ({ el }) => {
  locationInfo.$mount(el);
}
```

Thanks for any help or suggestion!